# Not show "Notice: Undefined index" in php

Tags: php, undefined

When entering a page that does not have the variables defined, the following error is observed:

Notice: Undefined index blah blah

What I want is that you do not see this, I need to send another error website or print another message ...

I want that instead of all this I only see a line that says "error" something like a try {} but when I tried it did not turn out

Thank you very much for your attention, I hope you have given me to understand since I do not speak English.

example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPmZk.png

Comment: Just turn off `display_errors` ? (or better yet put the sanity checks in place so you don't get those errors in the first place)

Comment: You can use, `error_reporting(0);` which turns off all error reporting (will not show any errors) in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to fix the notices themselves, then you can simply add the following line to your code.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

This will hide notices, like the ones that you're getting, and show **all** other errors.

For more info about error reporting: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php